# Class in WooCommerce to show/hide with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to modify WooCommerce, to show a gift checkbox. And so far, it is showing it, but it isn't hidin /showing it when I click the checkbox.

The code I've been using on f`unctions.php` is:

```
/**
* Add the field to the checkout
**/
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes','wordimpress_custom_checkout_field' );

function wordimpress_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>' . __( 'Is this a gift?' ) . '</h3><p style="margin: 0 0 8px;">Please check below to indicate if this is a gift</p>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'gift_checkbox', array(
        'type'  => 'checkbox',
        'class' => array( 'gift-checkbox form-row-wide' ),
        'label' => __( 'Yes' ),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'gift_checkbox' ) );

    woocommerce_form_field( 'to_textbox', array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'class' => array( 'to-text form-row-wide' ),
        'label' => __( 'To' ),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'to_textbox' ) );

    woocommerce_form_field( 'from_textbox', array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'class' => array( 'from-text form-row-wide' ),
        'label' => __( 'From' ),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'from_textbox' ) );

    woocommerce_form_field( 'message_textbox', array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'class' => array( 'message-text form-row-wide' ),
        'label' => __( 'Message' ),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'message_text' ) );

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Now I try to hide it in css witht:

```
.to-text{ display:none; }
.from-text{ display:none; }
.message-text{ display:none; }
```

And my jQuery code that I'm using in `script.js` is:

```
$( ".gift-checkbox " ).click(function() {
    $( ".to-text form-row-wide" ).slideToggle();
    $( ".from-text form-row-wide" ).slideToggle();
    $( ".message-text form-row-wide" ).slideToggle();
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

I don't understand why isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1). `.slideToggle();` function **doesn't work** with `display:none;` css.

Instead use `visibility:hidden;` css or use the `hide();` function at initialization in your JS script.

2). In wordpress you need to use `jQuery` instead of the `$` shorthand as this:
*(with the corrected code by @bob0the0mighty)*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery( ".to-text" ).slideToggle();
    jQuery( ".from-text" ).slideToggle();
    jQuery( ".message-text" ).slideToggle();

});
```

And the CSS:

```
.to-text, .from-text, .message-text{ 
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

3). If you want to use the `$` shorthand you will need to include this in your JS script:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){   

    //your code goes here

});
```

So it will be…

JS Script:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".to-text" ).slideToggle();
    $( ".from-text" ).slideToggle();
    $( ".message-text" ).slideToggle();

});
```

CSS:

```
.to-text, .from-text, .message-text{ 
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

4) If you want to use the css `display:none;`, you better have to use also `.addClass()` , `.hasClass()`, `.removeClass()`, `.toggleClass()` and `.css()` functions in addition in your JS script.

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are incorrect.

```
$( ".to-text form-row-wide" ).slideToggle();
$( ".from-text form-row-wide" ).slideToggle();
$( ".message-text form-row-wide" ).slideToggle();
```

should be

```
$( ".to-text" ).slideToggle();
$( ".from-text" ).slideToggle();
$( ".message-text" ).slideToggle();
```

Also, you should change the classes to ids unless there could be multiples.

Comment: Didn't worked, also tried to use ids like this:

     $( "#to_textbox_field" ).slideToggle();
     $( "#from_textbox_field" ).slideToggle();
     $( "#message_text_field" ).slideToggle();

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? There may be other things going on.

Comment: No, no errors at all. It's very strange that it isn't working =(

Comment: My guess is you have something else going on, possibly a JS error of some sort. Insert some console.log statements and see if anything gets printed to your browsers console.

Comment: @PedAltuve: Did you check if the click function is working on first place? Can you show the html output of the fields along with its parent container?